# A really big database size

Tags: 6, database, backups

I'm dumping the database every 2 days, but I noticed that at some point last month the database jumped from around 500 MB to 4 GB!

What can be the cause of it?

Comment: its probably best that you go into the database through mysql browser, phpmyadmin or whatever and see which tables have a massive amount of records and then update your question to ask what is causing that massive amount of records in that particular table.

Comment: A frist step would be to clear your cache and watchdog tables. Sometimes this helpes a lot.

Comment: @Moshe – please post back here with what tables were large so that other users can get help from this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One reasons that a database can grow w/o bound is when you don't have [cron](http://drupal.org/cron) setup to run.  Check your "Recent Log messages" at **/admin/reports/dblog**  and filter for cron, and make sure it is running (nightly is a good start).

On of the things cron does is prune the cache, watchdog, and sessions tables.  These can fill up quickly with data that isn't critical to Drupal running.

Occasionally, clearing these out can take too long for a cron run.  If this is the case, running a manual query, such as

```
DELETE FROM watchdog;
```

may be needed.  As mentioned above, you can run this on the `cache` and tables beginning with `cache_`, `watchdog`, and `sessions`.  It is always best to take a backup first, before running `DELETE` queries.

Comment: I have cron jobs, and I ran it manually and immediately dumped and it's still huge. deleted manually the watchdog, and still no help...

Comment: Did you run the query that @Letharion gave to see which tables are big?

Comment: Thanks for posting these great ideas. I had a database dump getting truncated using mysqldump. The resulting file was 500M. 500M limit somewhere? After clearing cache and session tables the dump is 21M New best practice, clear cache before backing up data :-)

Comment: Turns out the Devel module had to be turned off before creating a database backup with Backup & Migrate (otherwise you'll end up with a large database file).

Answer (score 6):

Run

```
show table status;
```

on your database, and take a look at the "Data_length" column. There you will see which tables take up the space.
I don't know how you dump your data, but if you use [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate), the cache tables are by default not included, saving quite a bit of space.

Answer (score 0):

If you have drush installed, run drush cron followed by drush cc all. That should fix the problem. Just reduced my db size from 4.3G to 65M.