# How to trim content from a heavy database

Tags: 7, database

I would like to trim content from a heavy production database (1GB), to reduce transfering time, local mysql import time and generally make it easier to work with.

I know I can [ignore cache, watchdog and index tables](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/a-really-big-database-size) and this reduces size greatly (about 50%) and I looked into deleting old [node revisions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16471/how-i-can-delete-all-node-field-revisions).

But I'm looking further to, for example, remove all content older than 1 year, or all users that have not been active in the last 6 months.

In the workflow these clean-up operations could be done in a (recently synched) staging environement before exporting the databse for local usage.

Anyone know how to accomplish removing older content from a database so it can be easier exported?

Comment: *"Anyone know how to accomplish this?"* what *this*, exactly? You asked about several hardly related things, like detection of users with no recent activity, node revisions, old content deletion etc - for each of these there will be different answer. And we can't design a whole workflow for you, too big task for simple Q&A format.

Comment: I narrowed the question down a bit.

Comment: `DELETE FROM node WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)` or similar?

Answer (score 2):

For content, I know two options, both based on [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views):

1. Create a view of old content only, and use [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) to purge it from your site. This is literally what you asked for, but also something I would discourage.
2. Create a view of new content only, and use [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to only export nodes recent enough to matter. That way you will still have old content on site, and only lose it if site crashes and you need to restore from incomplete backup.

Also, I suggest you to evaluate [Universally Unique IDentifier](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid), it helps with consistency if you are exporting data individually, not as a complete snapshot of entire site.